# Examples of nontrivial local systems in Decomposition Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, examples, perverse-sheaves, sheaf-theory

There is a proper map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ of projective varieties. The Decomposition Theorem of Beilinson–Bernstein–Deligne-Gabber states that

$$Rf∗IC_X  \cong \oplus_a IC_{\bar{Y_a}}(L_a)[shifts]$$

My question is: what are some interesting classes of examples maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$ such that the local systems $L_a$ we get on the right hand side above is nontrivial?

Right now I could only think of examples like finite branched coverings of projective spaces, $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $z$ gets mapped to $z^n$ for some positive integer $n$, Springer resolution, etc.

Comment: There are many many examples, e.g. universal families of elliptic curves over modular curves.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the following survey:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0349.pdf?

I find it very useful, very nice to read and it contains plenty of examples.